# Reading a YAML file in Mule

Tags: mule

I'm having trouble reading a YAML file that consists of a list in MuleSoft.

I have my YAML file set up as a Configuration property in my Global Elements, in the following structure.

```
applications:
  - appId: "123456"
    appName: Application One
  - appId: "456789"
    appName: Application Two
```

I am able to read the values when there's no list. But when I have it set up as a list, MuleSoft throws this error:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'test', see below        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifact [test]
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: ConfigurationPropertiesException: Configuration properties does not support type a list of complex types. Complex type keys are: appId,appName
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException: ConfigurationPropertiesException: Configuration properties does not support type a list of complex types. Complex type keys are: appId,appName
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: Configuration properties does not support type a list of complex types. Complex type keys are: appId,appName
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.config.internal.dsl.model.config.ConfigurationPropertiesException: Configuration properties does not support type a list of complex types. Complex type keys are: appId,appName
```

Pleas help me out: Is this not the right way to use a YAML file? Do I need to change my format?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuration properties does not support types that are a list of complex types. The properties have to be converted into spring properties on the backend

You can only use simple lists:
    applications:
      - "123456"
      - "456789"

But a simple object would work just as well for properties:

```
applications:
  "123456":
      name: Application One
  "456789":
      name: Application Two
```

Then you could look up dynamically by the appId like:

```
<set-variable variableName="appId" value="123456"  />
<logger level="INFO" message="#[p('applications.' ++ vars.appId ++ '.name')]" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way that I can call or print all the application numbers? For example something like `applications.$` or `applications.key`? I was hoping to be able to iterate through the different application.

Comment: use `${applications} pluck $$` to iterate over keys